# Clear scroll in OpenSearch/ElasticSearch with read only permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, authorization, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I want to fetch documents form an opensearch index with read_only permissions using the Scroll API. I tried these permissions for my role

```
indices:data/read/scroll/clear
indices:data/read/scroll
read
```

and

```
read
```

But when I run (using the python sdk):

```py
self.client.clear_scroll(scroll_id=scroll_ids_str)
```

when the opensearch package tries to run

```py
return self.transport.perform_request(
            "DELETE", "/_search/scroll", params=params, headers=headers, body=body
        )
```

I get this autorization error as a warning:

```bash
AuthorizationException(403, 'security_exception', {'error': {'root_cause': [
  {'type': 'security_exception', 'reason': 'no permissions for [indices:data/read/scroll/clear] and User [name=arn:aws:iam::<AWSID>:user/<NAME>, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]'}], 
 'type': 'security_exception', 'reason': 'no permissions for [indices:data/read/scroll/clear] and User [name=arn:aws:iam::<AWSID>:user/<NAME>, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]'}, 'status': 403})
```

Note that I explicitly added the suggested permission to my role. Also, I can successfully fetch all the desired documents, but I do not like that the warning suggests that I am not cleaning up some resources.

QUESTION: How do I successfully delete the scroll context with read only permissions?

Version: `opensearch-py==2.2.0`

Comment: Cluster level permissions? Is the requested tenant intentionally null? Does the original scroll operation itself work when you use `indices:data/read/scroll` ? I think it's related to being unable to perform the DELETE request. Take a look at: https://forum.search-guard.com/t/query-regarding-scroll-and-clear-permission/2026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling is good because there is a 10k document-retrieval limit otherwise that can only be up-configured server-side.

But OS/ES permissions are a bit fiddly to get right, as I'm sure you know already. The opensearch python documentation is also slightly disparate.

For reference there's a complete list here: https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security/access-control/permissions

In your specific case I came across the following helpful thread:

https://forum.search-guard.com/t/query-regarding-scroll-and-clear-permission/2026

So you should be able to add

```
indices:data/read/scroll/clear
```

to your cluster-level permissions. I *think* that's because in REST speak the DELETE operation has the same citizenship as GET, POST etc. so requires a bit more attention. You can test this out in the OS console sandbox but I can see why you might be nervous to test out DELETE operations there.

Don't forget that in general index permissions usually need *some* (parent) cluster permissions i.e. one higher.

Also in general OS/ES permissions are very restrictive by default (but include RBAC and multi-tenancy), unless you start putting `*` everywhere. For the sake of others this is another hierarchical example where index-level permissions need to be activated by specifying to which indices/indexes they apply. The granularity even extends to the document field level. The corollary is the need for specificity. Don't be tempted to start putting `*` everywhere! :)

Have fun and good luck!